# Proxy servers and captcha

Tags: proxy, captcha

Captcha isn't shown if I surf some websites through proxy servers. I haven't removed any scripts and objects.

Comment: Well isn't that just dandy.

Answer (score 1):

Simple, don't use proxy servers.  Proxying scripts through a web site can prevent many bits of code from working.  For example, scripts that attempt to keep a session open, or scripts that verify the source the script came from... etc.  Many sites that use captchas and other such security mechanisms don't want you to proxy, as it bypasses the whole purpose for security mechanisms like captchas in the first place.

Comment: Proxy servers are not web sites. They work at a slightly lower level - usually by forwarding HTTP requests in a way that's entirely transparent to scripts or CAPTCHAs, which aren't supposed to protect against proxies anyway (they're mostly used against automated crawlers). The "web site" kind is usually called a "CGI proxy", and you're right about it breaking many pages, but I don't think the question is about this type: it does mention "proxy _server_".

Comment: I know exactly how a proxy server works, as I've created several myself for a variety of reasons.  No, they are not entirely transparent to scripts & captchyas...

Comment: I think you're still not understanding that there are different kinds of "proxy servers"... Could you provide an example of your created software?